# Is there a way to automatically build a dependency in package.json?

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json, firebaseui

I use firebaseui, and I need [to build it](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#building-firebaseui) with french localization because the localized versions are not published to npm. My current `package.json` looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebaseui": "^3.5.2"
}
```

Is there a way to change it so that `firebaseui` is built with [`build-js-fr`](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#building-firebaseui) parameter on `npm install`?

Comment: Sounds like what you should at the very least also be doing is asking about getting them to publish the localizations so you can `require('firebaseui/fr')` instead of having to build things yourself, on their issue tracker.

Comment: agreed, unless you'd like to customize the localization, I don't see why you should be building it in the first place. Let's get this published! 

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more direct solution, I don't recommend it and it's only a proof of concept to get you started, but you can use the `postinstall` script in `package.json` to execute a script after `npm i`.

You would have something like this:

```json
"script": {
    "postinstall": "./postinstall.sh",
}
```

Create the `postinstall.sh` script and make it executable:

```bash
touch postinstall.sh
chmod u+x postinstall.sh
```

Then you can clone the repo and build it directly, here's an example `postinstall.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

git clone https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web.git
cd firebaseui-web
git checkout v3.5.2
npm i

for language in fr en es
do
    npm run build build-js-$language
done
```

But this will take a lot of time to run. [Marcel Falliere's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55654184/1092815) sounds better. I tried running the build command from the `firebaseui` folder in `node_modules`. You'll need `gulp`, but you will hit an error due to missing `gulpfile.js`.

I tested the solution posted above here on github:
https://github.com/GabLeRoux/npm-build-firebaseui-postinstall-example

*Note that this will probably fail on windows. This is only a proof of concept*

Answer (score 2):

As we can find in [this Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react/issues/21) :

> [Localization] May come later down the road.

I would not recommend having a local fork with your own build, because you will diverge from the main repo thus loosing upgrades and such. However, a comment on this issue suggest using [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package), an npm module that would allow you to make a "band-aid". Seems fine by me.

So I would suggest the following plan :

- You update the way `firebaseui` is built, directly inside your `node_modules` folder.
- Then `npx patch-package firebaseui`, which will create a `paches/firebaseui-3.5.2.patch`.
- Add this folder to your source control, and every team member will get the patch on `npm i`.
- Once the `firebaseui` lib get i18n right, you ditch the patch.